# "Position: Fixed" causing problems

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with position: fixed. Here's my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Horizontal Menus</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="button" href="">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a class="button" href="">Links</a></li> 
    <li><a class="button" href="">Forums</a></li> 
    <li><a class="button" href="">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <p>test</p>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .button {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: 700 1.2em Helvetica,Arial,serif;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: .4em .8em .4em .8em;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    ul {
    padding: .5em;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    }

    li {
    display: inline;
    }

    a {
    color: red;
    }

    a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    }
```

The site shows up like
        [this](https://gyazo.com/68dcd9bdc38f2cfdb13135d63d008bc7) with a fixed position, and it shows up like 
        [this](https://gyazo.com/f5b7b29f88c601bfab71dab5c0d00f63) without a fixed position. I want it to operate like a fixed position, but I also want to keep the navigation bat the way it previously was. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add `width: 100%` or `left: 0; right: 0`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: 700 1.2em Helvetica, Arial, serif;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: .4em .8em .4em .8em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: .5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Horizontal Menus</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="button" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="button" href="">Links</a></li>
      <li><a class="button" href="">Forums</a></li>
      <li><a class="button" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <p>test</p>
</body>

</html>
```